# Seletor css com nth e not

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Tenho um formulário com `flexbox`, só que quando da um erro é inserida uma `div` de `alert`, quebrando o `layout`.

Tem alguns campos que são 50% na mesma linha

```
<form method="post" action="XXX" class="form-login">
    @if($message = session('message'))
        <div class="alert-error">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="xxx" value="{{ old('xxx') }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="xxx" value="{{ old('xxx') }}">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-logar">
        Logar
    </button>
</form>
```

E no `css` tenho

```
 .form-login.form-group:nth-of-type(1),
 .form-login.form-group:nth-of-type(2) {
     width: 48.3%;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
 }
```

Isso acontece pois estou usando `nth-of-type`, **qual seria um `workaround`?**

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código que você tem no momento?

Comment: Um momento, estou pelo celular, já acrescento

Comment: Coloquei um código de exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução mais simples, para não usar nth-of-type, é usar as classes **form-group** que você já tem nos grupos de campos. Então seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
.form-login .form-group {
    width: 48.3%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Caso queira usar o nth, poderia ser feito assim:

```
.form-login .form-group:nth-of-type(n+1) {
    width: 48.3%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: gostei da solução e funcionou mto bem! obrigado!